# Assisstance with comparisons in primitive recursion

Tags: recursion, computer-science, computation-theory

I have been given the following question on a tutorial about recursive functions and am not sure how to compare two arguments

```
  Show that the sign function, sign: N  -> N, is primitive recursive where
            sign(x)=  x>0 : x=1
                      x=0 : x=0
    Note the number of arguments of sign.
```

I already know that I will use

> succ(zero(x)

to assign 1 and

> zero(x)

to assign 0 but I do not know compare the x to zero.

Comment: What is the definition of "primitive recursive" in that context?

Comment: A new function f can be constructed from existing functions g 
and h by primitive recursion as follows: 
 
 f (x, 0) ≝ g (x) 
 f (x, y+1) ≝ h (x, y, f (x, y) )

Comment: 'xcuse me, but I don't see how this function is recursive at all. So `sign 0 = 0; sign (n+1) = 1` done